# How to define actionFunction in controller?

Tags: dynamic-vf-component

It is possible to define actionFunction with Dynamiccomponent?

`Component.Apex.ActionFunction af = new  Component.Apex.ActionFunction ();`

please give me one example .

Here is my Vf:

```
<apex:page controller="pageController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!pageBlock}" id="me1"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public with sharing class pageController {

        public String HtmlData{get;set;}
         public pageController() 
         {  }
    public PageReference getTab() 
    {
       Component.Apex.PageBlock pblock2=new Component.Apex.PageBlock();
       Component.Apex.pageBlockSection pgsection1 = new Component.Apex.pageBlockSection ();
       pgsection1.title = 'Sage';

       String tabname =   ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('p1'); 
       HtmlData = 'Welcome '+HtmlData ;
       pblock2.childComponents.add(pgsection1)
       return null;
    }
    public List<String> tabList{get;set;}
      public Component.Apex.PageBlock getpageBlock()
      {
           tabList = new List<String>();
           tabList.add('Main Info');
           tabList.add('Company Info');
           tabList.add('About us');
           tabList.add('Customer Info');     
           Component.Apex.TabPanel panel = new Component.Apex.TabPanel(switchType = 'client',id='tp', value='{!currentTab}',title = 'CustomerDetailTabs');
           Component.Apex.PageBlock pb=new Component.Apex.PageBlock();              
           for(Integer i=0;i<tabList.size();i++)
           {
               Component.Apex.ActionFunction af = new Component.Apex.ActionFunction();     
               af = new Component.Apex.ActionFunction();
               set<String> test = new  set<String>(); 
               test.add('tab'+string.valueOf(i));
               Component.Apex.Tab tab = new  Component.Apex.Tab();
               tab.id = 'tab'+string.valueOf(i);
               tab.label = tabList[i];
               tab.ontabenter= 'callClass'+string.valueOf(i)+'(\''+tabList[i]+'\')';
               tab.rerender =test;
               ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('p1',tabList[i]); 
               af.name='callClass'+string.valueOf(i);
               af.reRender =test;
               af.expressions.action='{!getTab}';
               Component.Apex.pageBlockSection pgsection = new Component.Apex.pageBlockSection ();
               pgsection.title = 'Information';
               Component.Apex.OutputLabel header= new Component.Apex.OutputLabel();
               header.value = 'Name';
               Component.Apex.outputText textval= new Component.Apex.outputText();
               textval.value = 'Harshal';
               if(i==1)
               {   
                   HtmlData='SageIndia.com';
                   textval.id='demo1';
                   textval.value = HtmlData;   
               }
               pgsection.childComponents.add(header);
               pgsection.childComponents.add(textval);
               tab.childComponents.add(pgsection);
               panel.childComponents.add(tab);  
               tab.childComponents.add(af);
               pb.childComponents.add(panel);  
           }
           return pb; 
      } 
}
```

Comment: im trying to think of the use case for this.. perhaps you could expand on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well I have 4 tabs which i created on controller side  using dynamic component,now I want to show different page blocks on 4 different tabs?

Comment: above code contain my VF and controller ,can you please tell hoe to render the tabs and display my page blocks into the tabs.thanks in advance

Comment: @HarshalKolhe is the question then how to dynamically render `pageBlock` elements as children of `tab` elements? (and not ActionFunction as the title states)

Comment: Just give me one sample example that render the tabs which include action function on controller side using dynamic component?Unable to render the tabs.